# How to generate a sequence of values by specifying a start, end value, and step?

Tags: c++, stl

I need to generate a sequence of numbers, having a start, end value and a step with which the numbers will be generated.For example, in the Haskell language, this is a trivial problem, and it is called an arithmetic sequence.

```
[1..10] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I tried to implement this as follows.

```
namespace utility {
  template<class Container, class Type>
    Container generator(Type t_from, Type t_to, Type t_step = 1)
    {
      // Sequence storage container
      Container sequence_of_numbers { };
      sequence_of_numbers.reserve(static_cast<std::size_t>(std::abs(t_to - t_from + 1)) / t_step);

      // For floating point data
      if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<Type>) {
        // The reverse sequence
        if((t_to - t_from) < 0) {
          for(Type i = t_from; ; i -= t_step) {
            if(i > t_to) {
              sequence_of_numbers.push_back(static_cast<typename Container::value_type>(i));
            } else {
              if(std::fabs(i - t_to) < std::numeric_limits<Type>::epsilon()) {
                sequence_of_numbers.push_back(i);
              }
              break;
            }
          }
        // The direct sequence
        } else {
          for(Type i = t_from; ; i += t_step) {
            if(i < t_to) {
              sequence_of_numbers.push_back(static_cast<typename Container::value_type>(i));
            } else {
              if(std::fabs(i - t_to) < std::numeric_limits<Type>::epsilon()) {
                sequence_of_numbers.push_back(i);
              }
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      // Integer data type
      } else {
        if((t_to - t_from) < 0) {
          for(Type i = t_from; i >= t_to; i -= t_step) {
            sequence_of_numbers.push_back(static_cast<typename Container::value_type>(i));
          }
        } else {
          for(Type i = t_from; i <= t_to; i += t_step) {
            sequence_of_numbers.push_back(static_cast<typename Container::value_type>(i));
          }
        }
      }

      sequence_of_numbers.shrink_to_fit();

      return sequence_of_numbers;
    }
}
```

And the next call I get the desired result.

```
std::vector<int> full_reverse_sequence { utility::generator<std::vector<int>>(10000, 0) };
```

Is there something similar in C++17/C++20, at the syntax or STL library level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, [std::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) does what you need.

Or, you may use [std::generate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) or [std::generate_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) with a simple lambda

There is not much more to say.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> //std::iota
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    int size = 10;
    std::vector<int> x(size);
    
    int startNum = 50;
    int step = 2;

    std::generate(x.begin(), x.end(), [&startNum, &step]{ return startNum+=step;});

    for(auto i : x)
        std::cout << i << "  ";
    
    return 0;
}

Output: 52  54  56  58  60  62  64  66  68  70
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).